# jquery stores object in data as a reference, why?

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the bad title.

Please see the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pw9e0yun/2/

```
$(this).data("item", "item-no-" + (index));
$(this).data("options", options);  /* how to store options not as a reference */
```

I like how the data "item" is stored ("as is"). But I don't like how the data "options" is stored. This gave me a hard time to figure out for last couple of hours. Now I realize that the option is stored as kind of a reference. Why is this and how can I easily store the "at that time" values of the options object in the element's data.

Thanks for clarification.

(btw: the error "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" is stupid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stores it as a reference because that's how objects and references to them work in JavaScript. `data` writes to a storage area that's basically a JavaScript object you're adding properties to. (It doesn't, as some think, write to `data-*` attributes. It does initialize the data store from them, which sometimes surprises people.)

If you want to store a *copy* of the object, you have to copy it. There are lots of different ways to copy objects in JavaScript (including jQuery's own [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend)). Which one you use is entirely dependent on what your end goal is.

So this *might* work, depending on what `options` is and what your end goal is:

```
$(this).data("options", $.extend({}, options));
// or
$(this).data("options", $.extend(true, {}, options));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Although known, it's good to have such a very clear distiction between `data` and `data-*`. Both your solutions worked for me. I'm writing/extending a tab plugin. I wanted to store the options to the elements the plugin iterates over. All went fine as long as the options were static. But then I added the index (number) to the options for later use. That's when things got broken.